# NullReferenceException when calling method of a service in Index page in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My `Index` page has the `@code` block calling a service method:

```cs
@using BlazingPizza.Services

@inject PizzaService PizzaService

...

@code {
    private List<Pizza> specials = new List<Pizza>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        specials = await PizzaService.GetPizzasAsync();
    }
}
```

The service is already registered in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PizzaService>();
```

I also tried injecting the interface and declaring the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPizzaService, PizzaService>();
```

But whenever I call `GetPizzasAsync`, the exception happens.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
BlazingPizza.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync() in Index.razor
+
        specials = await PizzaService.GetPizzasAsync();
```

What am I missing? I am following official's tutorials.

Comment: Try out to put breakpoint in your method and find what is null there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The code you have posted looks largely OK. So it is in some other part...

Comment: Remove all the markup code and try again. Post a full stack trace and a complete page if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPizzaService, PizzaService>();` but inject the *Interface instead of the Class*:

```
@inject IPizzaService PizzaService
```

Now `PizzaService` is implemented correctly and the `GetPizzaAsync()` method can be used to populate your specials list.